# fill polygons in google map/earth

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-earth

My KML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Style id="s1">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>7f0000ff</color>
        <width>4</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <color>7f0000ff</color>
        <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
        <fill>1</fill>
        <outline>1</outline>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <name>All isolation countries</name>
    <description>All isolation countries</description>
    <Placemark>
      <styleUrl>#s1</styleUrl>
      <name>Indonesia</name>
      <Polygon>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>102.4918975830078,1.259721994400024,0 102.3088989257813,1.420554995536804,0 102.1374969482422,1.448055028915405,0 102.0785980224609,1.485000014305115,0 101.9944000244141,1.600000023841858,0 102.0065994262695,1.619166970252991,0 102.4349975585938,1.527500033378601,0 102.4779968261719,1.502221941947937,0 102.4954986572266,1.436308026313782,0 102.504997253418,1.273888945579529,0 102.4918975830078,1.259721994400024,0</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
        <innerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>102.4918975830078,1.259721994400024,0 102.3088989257813,1.420554995536804,0 102.1374969482422,1.448055028915405,0 102.0785980224609,1.485000014305115,0 101.9944000244141,1.600000023841858,0 102.0065994262695,1.619166970252991,0 102.4349975585938,1.527500033378601,0 102.4779968261719,1.502221941947937,0 102.4954986572266,1.436308026313782,0 102.504997253418,1.273888945579529,0 102.4918975830078,1.259721994400024,0</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </innerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <styleUrl>#s1</styleUrl>
      <name>Ecuador</name>
      <Polygon>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-90.61167907714844,-0.3755556046962738,0 -90.77166748046875,-0.344166785478592,0 -90.87222290039063,-0.2652778923511506,0 -90.79332733154297,-0.149444505572319,0 -90.77362060546876,-0.1550000011920929,0 -90.58556365966797,-0.2455555945634842,0 -90.55029296875,-0.3091666996479035,0 -90.61167907714844,-0.3755556046962738,0</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
        <innerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-90.61167907714844,-0.3755556046962738,0 -90.77166748046875,-0.344166785478592,0 -90.87222290039063,-0.2652778923511506,0 -90.79332733154297,-0.149444505572319,0 -90.77362060546876,-0.1550000011920929,0 -90.58556365966797,-0.2455555945634842,0 -90.55029296875,-0.3091666996479035,0 -90.61167907714844,-0.3755556046962738,0</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </innerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
```

...

It works in google earth and map but whatever I try the polygons do not fill. Is there a way to fill them? Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason you have an outerBoundaryIs and an innerBoundaryIs that are identical.  Inner boundaries are normally only used if you have "donut holes", but in this case your "hole" is (exactly) as big as the polygon itself so it appears like an unfilled polygon.  You need to get rid of the "innerBoundaryIs".  So for example in the Indonesia polygon delete the following:

```
<innerBoundaryIs>
  <LinearRing>
    <coordinates>-90.61167907714844,-0.3755556046962738,0 -90.77166748046875,-0.344166785478592,0 -90.87222290039063,-0.2652778923511506,0 -90.79332733154297,-0.149444505572319,0 -90.77362060546876,-0.1550000011920929,0 -90.58556365966797,-0.2455555945634842,0 -90.55029296875,-0.3091666996479035,0 -90.61167907714844,-0.3755556046962738,0</coordinates>
  </LinearRing>
</innerBoundaryIs>
```

You should also add a tessellation because these are very big polys and you want them to follow the curvature of the earth...i.e. Just after "Polygon" use "tessellate" (it's either 1 or 0 for on or off).  Lastly, you want your altitude mode to be "clampedToGround"

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Style id="s1">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>7f0000ff</color>
        <width>4</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <color>7f0000ff</color>
        <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
        <fill>1</fill>
        <outline>1</outline>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <name>All isolation countries</name>
    <description>All isolation countries</description>



    <Placemark>
      <styleUrl>#s1</styleUrl>
      <name>Indonesia</name>
      <Polygon>
      <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>clampedToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>102.4918975830078,1.259721994400024,0 102.3088989257813,1.420554995536804,0 102.1374969482422,1.448055028915405,0 102.0785980224609,1.485000014305115,0 101.9944000244141,1.600000023841858,0 102.0065994262695,1.619166970252991,0 102.4349975585938,1.527500033378601,0 102.4779968261719,1.502221941947937,0 102.4954986572266,1.436308026313782,0 102.504997253418,1.273888945579529,0 102.4918975830078,1.259721994400024,0</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>

      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <styleUrl>#s1</styleUrl>
      <name>Ecuador</name>
      <Polygon>
      <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>clampedToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-90.61167907714844,-0.3755556046962738,0 -90.77166748046875,-0.344166785478592,0 -90.87222290039063,-0.2652778923511506,0 -90.79332733154297,-0.149444505572319,0 -90.77362060546876,-0.1550000011920929,0 -90.58556365966797,-0.2455555945634842,0 -90.55029296875,-0.3091666996479035,0 -90.61167907714844,-0.3755556046962738,0</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>

      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    </Document>
    </kml>
```

Comment: Excellent thank you! I was wondering about the innerBoundaryIs but when I left them out things looked funny - probably because I did not clampedToGround.